# Dedicated writer process with only readers in another process

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, lucene.net

I'm working on a ASP.Net MVC 5 application that implements full text search using Lucene.net.

Due to the [potentional problems](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) with hosting background tasks in ASP.Net, I was pondering whether the following scenario would be viable:

1. Move the sole Lucene writer to a dedicated process that periodically checks the database for unindexed rows and updates the lucene index accordingly
2. Keep the readers inside the ASP.NET worker process

Would that work using FSDirectory at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this working just fine with the help of a little helper class I wrote for the project. The factory class below shares a single indexReader with any number of threads and ensures that the reader returned from GetCurrentReader() is kept in sync with the state of the index.

```
class IndexReaderFactory :
  IDisposable
{
  public IndexReaderFactory(bool isReadonly)
  {
    this.isReadonly = isReadonly;
  }

  IndexReader reader;
  readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim rwl = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
  private readonly bool isReadonly;

  /// <summary>
  /// Returns a reader that isCurrent
  /// </summary>
  public IndexReader GetUpToDateReader()
  {
    rwl.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();

    try
    {
      if (reader == null)
      {
        rwl.EnterWriteLock();

        try
        {
          if (logger.IsInfoEnabled)
            logger.Info("Creating IndexReader on directory {0}", AppSettingsBase.LucenePostIndexLocation);

          reader = IndexReader.Open(FSDirectory.Open(AppSettingsBase.LucenePostIndexLocation), isReadonly);
        }

        finally
        {
          rwl.ExitWriteLock();
        }
      }

      else if(!reader.IsCurrent())
      {
        rwl.EnterWriteLock();

        try
        {
          if (logger.IsInfoEnabled)
            logger.Info("IndexReader is not current. Re-opening");

          reader = reader.Reopen();
        }

        finally
        {
          rwl.ExitWriteLock();
        }
      }
    }

    finally 
    {
      rwl.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
    }

    return reader;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  public void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (disposing)
    {
      // get rid of managed resources
    }

    if(reader != null)
      reader.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be possible. You can have multiple IndexReaders concurrently and it should be fine, and it even have an external lock feature (file system based) for multi-process locking.

Remember that an IndexReader will search in the current "snapshot" from when it was created, so you should find a way to "dump" IndexReaders when the index change. You could of course create an IndexReader for every search but that is probably not recommended, and will fail if you currently are writing to the index. For those purposes, ou can retrieve a reader from the current writer, but that won't be an option for you since they will reside in different processes.

You might find this article interesting as well:

http://devlearnings.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/lucene-reuse-indexsearcher-rather-creating-new-everytime/

Comment: Why do you think opening a reader would fail if the index is currently written to?

Comment: @OliverWeichhold Well, maybe it wouldn't fail, but you could end up in a state where a reader will have no index, or inconsistent state. I don't really remember how the lock affect readers.